# Error in creating IAM role and attach policies to it

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a lambda role and attach policies to it so it can start and stop ec2 instance. I will be triggering the lambda using cloudwatch.

I am getting this error: 
"Error: Error creating IAM Role lambdaRole: MalformedPolicyDocument: JSON strings must not have leading spaces
        status code: 400, request id: d6a86c41-6601-43af-9040-81f6e6a76ec8

on iam.tf line 11, in resource "aws_iam_role" "lambdaRole":
  11: resource "aws_iam_role" "lambdaRole" {"

```
 terraform {
    backend  "s3" {
    region         = "us-west-2"
    bucket         = "gitlegionbucket"
    key            = "ec2/terraform.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table = "tf-state-lock"
    }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambdaRole" {
  name = "lambdaRole"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Principal": {
          "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Sid": ""
        }
      ]
    }
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name        = "test-policy"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Start*",
        "ec2:Stop*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach-policies" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.lambdaRole.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.policy.arn}"
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2686....kindly check if there is any white space after EOF

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was also facing the same error. I have directly copied the code from the question.

The way it worked was for me was to start the `{` i.e the start of the policy after the `EOF` line immediately without any spaces.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambdaRole" {
  name = "lambdaRole"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": ""
    }
    ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name        = "test-policy"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Start*",
        "ec2:Stop*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach-policies" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.lambdaRole.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.policy.arn}"
}
```

**terraform output:**

```
aws_iam_role.lambdaRole: Creating...
aws_iam_role.lambdaRole: Creation complete after 2s [id=lambdaRole]
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.attach-policies: Creating...
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.attach-policies: Creation complete after 1s [id=lambdaRole-20191107141649610400000001]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a solution to this problem. I moved the jsons into different files and I just referred to those files instead.

like this, policy = "${file("lambda-policy.json")}"

and this I have in "lambda-policy.json" : 
        {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                    "ec2:StartInstances",
                    "logs:*",
                    "ec2:StopInstances"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }